# How to redirect file to execute in header.php

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to solve a problem regarding how to animate font awesome menu bars to toggle click.

I haven't been able to but, to get around it, I've created a file in my theme folder and called it `Menu Bars`. In this file I placed the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta name="viewport" 
content="width=device- 
width, initial-scale=1">

<style>


.container {

display: inline-block;

cursor: pointer;

}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {

width: 35px;

height: 5px;

background-color: #333;

margin: 6px 0;

transition: 0.4s;

}

.change .bar1 {

-webkit-transform: 
rotate(-45deg) 
translate(-9px, 6px);

transform: rotate(-45deg) 
translate(-9px, 6px);

}.change .bar2 {opacity: 
0;} .change .bar3 {

-webkit-transform: 
rotate(45deg) 
translate(-8px, -8px);

transform: rotate(45deg) 
translate(-8px, -8px);

}

</style>

</head>

<body>



<div class="container" 
onclick="myFunction(this)">

<div class="bar1"></div>

<div class="bar2"></div>

<div class="bar3"></div>

</div>

<script>

function myFunction(x) {

x.classList.toggle
("change");

}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Then I looked in my header.php and replaced `<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>`with

```
<?php header("Location: 
home/qpgteouc/public_
html/wp- 
content/themes/shapel
y/Menu"); ?>
```

I assumed this would redirect to this file `Menu Bars in location:

```
home/qpgteouc/public_
html/wp- 
content/themes/shapel
y/Menu
```

and execute the file, so creating the menu bars animation which I want.

What actually happened was that the site refused to load on grounds of `too many redirects`.

Is what I'm trying to do possible and if so what do i need to do?

Here's what i have so far after helpful suggestions but still not working.

```
<header id="masthead" class="site- 
header<?php echo get_theme_mod( 
'mobile_menu_on_desktop', true ) ? ' mobile-menu' : ''; ?>" role="banner">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <nav <?php echo $style; ?> id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <div class="container nav-bar">
                <div class="flex-row">
                    <div class="module left site-title-container">
                        <?php shapely_get_header_logo(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="module widget-handle mobile-toggle right visible-sm visible-xs">

                        <?php require("home/qpgteouc/public_html/wp-content/themes/shapely/Menu_bars_"); ?>





                    </div>

                    <div class="module-group right">    
                        <div class="module left">


                            <?php shapely_header_menu(); ?>
                        </div>

                        <!--end of menu module-->
                        <div class="module widget-handle search-widget-handle hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                            <div class="search">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                <span class="title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Site Search', 'shapely' ); ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="function">
                                <?php
                                get_search_form();
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--end of module group-->
                </div>
            </div>

        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </div>
```

Comment: @Utkanos thanks, so what do i do? It would know because of file extention`Menu` at the end...?

Comment: header("Location ... etc tells the browser to forget about the page it was trying to load and go to a different one entirely. That's not the same as including some extra info within the same page. I'm not sure you really want to redirect to a page which includes just the menu and nothing else?? I suspect you need to _include_ the relevant HTML and CSS for your menu bars within the main page you're trying to load. (Of course such an included file must not have it's own html head and body tags, they must only appear once in the whole final document)

Comment: Why do you redirecting to the file?
Why you don't require("home/qpgteouc/public_html/wp- content/themes/shapely/Menu");

Comment: @ADyson yes, how do i do that please?

Comment: By using the `include` or `require` command to load that file's contents into the current script. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: @ADyson please see additional info in question. Done as suggested. Not working....

Comment: The file is really just called `Menu_bars_` with no extension or anything? Are you sure? I'd have expected it might be `Menu_bars_.html` or `Menu_bars_.php` or similar. P.S. "not working" is not a helpful description. What _exactly_ happens when you run your code right now? Do you get an error or warning in your log file (or on screen) perhaps? Or some other unexpected behaviour. Please be specific about the problem, it gives us a much higher chance of being able to fix it. Otherwise, we can only make guesses, as I've just done.

Comment: P.P.S. As I mentioned before, you also need to get rid of `<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta name="viewport" 
content="width=device- 
width, initial-scale=1">` and `</head>

<body>` and `</body>

</html>` from your Menu Bars file. You are going to be including this code inside a HTML document, so it's not valid to then have tags which declare another HTML document within it.

Comment: @ADyson If i remove body tag the javascript won't execute will it?

Comment: @ADyson tried what you suggested just getting `critical error` message.

Comment: "If i remove body tag the javascript won't execute will it?" ...no idea where you got that idea from. Remember, you are putting this code _inside another document_. So it'll be included _inside_ another `<body>` tag which is generated elsewhere, earlier in your code. Anyway it's the `<script` tag which marks the code as being Javascript.

Comment: "just getting critical error message" ...is that literally all it says? or is there more detail? Have you checked the PHP error log file?

Comment: P.S. Is it the error described here:  https://wpfixit.com/wordpress-error-there-has-been-a-critical-error-on-your-website/ ? If so then that blog talks to you about fixing it. Did you google the error yourself at all? P.S. I'm not a wordpress expert, but the basic principles would be similar in all PHP apps anyway - read the link about debugging which is linked from the error page.

Answer (score 0):

`header("Location: *");` redirecting the page always and so the browser redirecting you everythime to the same site. So you have to use [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php).
Example

```
<?php require("home/qpgteouc/public_html/wp-content/themes/shapely/Menu"); ?>
```

Comment: Tried replacing my code with yours, in the way I've outlined above but it just breaks the site and reports `critical error

Comment: yeah... The file itself is called `Menu Bars`but when i check the path it's correct as listed above. It's just saved as a read file. Could saving it as some other extention have an effect?